# "A senior English master", what is it?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"A senior English master", what is it? If it means "a master degree, a type of postgraduate degree", then I don't see how it fits the rest of the narrative. The character is described as "purposeless", the one who "had never had a success" and failed examinations. Having a postgraduate degree is not something that is commonly associated with "purposeless" losers, especially back then. Does it mean something else? Wells's short story The Inexperienced Ghost

> He told me how he had been killed—he went down into a London basement with a candle to look for a leakage of gas—and described himself as a **senior English master** in a London private school when that release occured.

Comment: The Clue is "senior English master in **a London private school**" , Pointing to "teacher" , Other things suggest that he was not very smart , hence , he was looking for gas leakage with a burning candle !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A senior English master

[Master](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoolmaster) here means a male school teacher in British English. The term is short for [schoolmaster](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/schoolmaster). The subject he teaches is English. The story was first published in 1902 when a lower quality school would not require rigorous qualifications from its teaching staff. Hence the character's lack of success at examinations would not prevent him taking up a teaching post.

H G Wells himself spent some time working as an [unqualified teacher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._G._Wells#Teacher).

The corresponding term for a female school teacher is [schoolmistress](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/schoolmistress), which can be shortened to mistress.

Both master and mistress are seen as old-fashioned terms now though less so when preceded by the name of the subject they teach, e.g. chemistry master, French mistress.

Comment: Is that a British expression? I've never heard "master" to refer to a teacher.

Comment: @gotube It is. It's short for school master. A female school teacher can be referred to as a school mistress or mistress. Both forms are now regarded as old-fashioned. We still used them in my UK grammar school in the 1970s.

Comment: The term Master is still in usage , like "Head Master" or "School Master" == "Presiding Officer of a School" ( I vaguely remember putting this comment earlier )

Comment: @Prem Master and mistress are still in use in BrE but regarded as old-fashioned. Teacher is now more common. Master or mistress can be any teacher in a school; only the [headteacher](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/headteacher) is in charge of the school.

Comment: I had masters in the 1960s at Alleyn's School, and one mistress (French, Dora Wiggs) but they are more touchy-feely these days.